# Send email to user on new term save depending on flagged content

Tags: rules, feeds, flags

I have a content type `'my_content'` with two nodes. These nodes can be flagged by each user (NOT global flag) with the flag `'my_flag'`. This content type has a field `'machine_name'`.

Now, using feeds I'm importing some content from xml to another content type that has also a field `machine_name` and one of the fields is a taxonomy term that is created if it doesn't exists.

What I want is to send an email to the users who flagged the nodes of `'my_content'` whenever a new term is created.

Example:

```
### 'my_content' ###
nodeA:
machine_name = Sidney
flagged = true

nodeB:
machine_name = London
flagged = false
```

Feeds imports an xml and creates a new taxonomy term. It also creates content where one of the fields is the machine_name. If that machine_name is 'Sidney', the email should be sent. If it's 'London', the email is not sent because nodeB is not flagged.

I think rules is the way to go but I'm unable to get the two conditions I need to have that are, a new node is created and a new taxonomy term is created.

Comment: I don't understand why you have two conditions. From this sentence of yours 'What I want is to send an email to the users who flagged the nodes of 'my_content' whenever a new term is created.' I only see one condition: new term created. Your action is complicated and I think you need to wire it into views so that views will get your list of users who flagged for which you then send the mail.

Comment: Hi J. Reynolds. Thanks for your answer. The condition to send the email is in fact only when a new term is created. But if userA didn't flag the content, only userB (that flagged) will receive it. That's why I have two conditions. Your suggestion to use views to have a list of users is a great idea. Will try that.

Comment: I forgot to mention something else. When the term is created I need to know which content was imported in feeds, compare one of the fields in that content to the same field in 'my_content'. That's why is complex. Or maybe I'm complicating myself...